# Mysqli num_rows always returning zero

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Mysqli is exhibiting a strange behavior. For any queries that I try the num_rows is always 0.

```
        $email = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con1,$_POST['email']));
        $pwd = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con1, $_POST['pwd']));
        $result = $con1->prepare("select login.email,login.pwd from login 
                  where email = ?");
        if(!$result)
        {
            echo("error");
        }

        $result->bind_param('s',$email);
        $result->execute();
        print_r($result); //num_rows is zero
        if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $result->bind_result($email1,$pwd1);
            $result->store_result();
            while($result->fetch())
            {
                echo("Email: ".$email1);

            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to take a look atthe `mysqli` reference. `mysqli_execute` returns a boolean, not a count of rows. If it's returning 0 (or false) then your query has failed and you need to look at with the SQL error is.

Comment: You forgot to store the result actually. So you `execute` it, which returns a boolean, and then you `store` the result, before you can execute the `num_rows`

Comment: @Dorvalla: Thanks. I just had to shift `$result->bind_result($email1,$pwd1);`
`$result->store_result();` before `if($result->num_rows > 0)` and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$email = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con1,$_POST['email']));
$pwd = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con1, $_POST['pwd']));
$result = $con1->prepare("select login.email,login.pwd from login 
          where email = ?");
if(!$result)
{
    echo("error");
}
$result->bind_param('s',$email);
$result->execute();
$num_row = $result->num_rows;
print_r($num_row); //num_rows is zero
if($num_row > 0)
{
    $result->bind_result($email1,$pwd1);
    $result->store_result();
    while($result->fetch())
    {
        echo("Email: ".$email1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an explanation of what you changed and why?

Comment: @kurdtpage What do you want to do ? My response was posted the 16 October 2016 hahha

Answer (score 0):

We have to store the result before we calling num_rows

```
$stmt->store_result();
```